# How to bind & save radio button values in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose

Here I'm using the nested property Schema of mongoose to nest all the "*stages*" then using formGroup in typescript.

> I'm not sure what should be the **formControlName** for the *radio
>   buttons* as it needs to be similar?

Also, not sure if I'm missing anything?

---

***Code:***

***// Schema***

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    stages: {
      stageOne:   { type: Boolean, default: false },
      stageTwo:   { type: Boolean, default: false },
      stageThree: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

---

***// typescript/component.ts***

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   name: [''],
   email: [''],
   stages: this.formBuilder.group({
     stageOne: [null],
     stageTwo: [null],
     stageThree: [null]
   });
});
```

---

***// html/template.html***

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input name="name" class="form-control" id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="name">
     <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email">

     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageOne" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="stageOne" formControlName="???">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageOne">1</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageTwo" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="stageTwo" formControlName="???">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageTwo">2</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageThree" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="stageThree" formControlName="???">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageThree">3</label>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is no different than with your other input form controls. However, the  `ControlValueAccessor` will get the value from your radio button so you do not require the additional `ngModel` directives. When you submit your form the from object itself, `this.form.value`, will contain all your form values.

**Reactive Form**

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   name: [''],
   email: [''],
   stages: ['1']
});
```

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input name="name" class="form-control" id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
     <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" type="email" formControlName="email">

     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageOne" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="stages" [value]="1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageOne">1</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageTwo" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="stages" [value]="2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageTwo">2</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="stageThree" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="stages" [value]="3">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="stageThree">3</label>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe for radio buttons the name/formControlName property needs to be same in order to select one of them otherwise it selects all the buttons and works as checkboxes.